# creating a column that based on another column in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

In my `data`, I've some `study`ies `reporting` both `subscale` and `composite`.

I want to add a new column called `include`. For `study`ies `reporting` both `subscale` and `composite`, in the rows that are `subscale`, `include` should be TRUE else it must be FALSE; any other row must be TRUE.

In other words, `include` can only be FALSE for `reporting==composite` ONLY in `study`ies that have reported both `subscale` and `composite`. Everywhere else `include` must be TRUE.

My desired output is below. Is this achievable in `R`?

```
library(tidyverse)
m="
study  reporting
1      subscale
1      composite
2      subscale
2      composite
3      composite
3      composite
4      composite
5      subscale"

data <- read.table(text = m, h=T)

desired =
"study  reporting  include
 1       subscale    TRUE
 1      composite   FALSE
 2       subscale    TRUE
 2      composite   FALSE
 3      composite    TRUE
 3      composite    TRUE
 4      composite    TRUE
 5      subscale     TRUE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(study) %>%
  mutate(
    include = !(
      "subscale" %in% reporting & 
      "composite" %in% reporting &
      reporting == "composite"
  ))
# # A tibble: 8 × 3
# # Groups:   study [5]
# study reporting include
# <int> <chr>     <lgl>  
# 1     1 subscale  TRUE   
# 2     1 composite FALSE  
# 3     2 subscale  TRUE   
# 4     2 composite FALSE  
# 5     3 composite TRUE   
# 6     3 composite TRUE   
# 7     4 composite TRUE   
# 8     5 subscale  TRUE
```

Comment: I would replace `reporting == "composite"` with `reporting == "subscale"`. It's symmetric...

Comment: The way I wrote it is more concise, but it might be easier to conceptualize as a `include = case_when("subscale" %in% reporting & 
      "composite" %in% reporting &
      reporting == "composite" ~ FALSE, TRUE ~ TRUE)`.